# Writing data into google sheet works in .ipynb but not in .py

Tags: python, google-sheets, sublimetext, jupyter-notebook

My script writes some data into a google spreadsheet. It works absolutely fine in iPython notebook but it doesn't from a .py file in Sublime (no errors, just nothing). Both files are located in the same folder together with the authorization file - 'client_secret.json'. Could anyone suggest why? Thank you!

My code:

```
import datetime as dt    
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

def googlesheet():
    # use creds to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('client_secret.json', scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(creds)    
    # Find a workbook by name and open the first sheet
    wsheet = client.open("google_cout").worksheet('Count')
    return wsheet

def next_available_row(sheet):
    str_list = filter(None, sheet.col_values(1))  # fastest
    return str(len(str_list)+1)

#insert on the next available row
def write_to_google(next_row, count):
    today = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%d %B")
    wsheet.update_acell("A{}".format(next_row), today)
    for i in count:
        if i == u'red':
            wsheet.update_acell("B{}".format(next_row), count[i])
        if i == u'blue':
            wsheet.update_acell("C{}".format(next_row), count[i])
    print('Done!')

def main():
    total_count = {u'red': 222, u'blue': 91}
    wsheet = googlesheet()
    next_row = next_available_row(wsheet)
    write_to_google(next_row, total_count)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work from a .py file in Sublime". Opening a file in Sublime will not execute it. Typically you'd execute the file from your shell. How are you executing the .py file?

Comment: Sorry, if I wasn't clear enough. I run the file from my shell: `python name_of_my_file.py`. The code works fine and prints the correct `total_count` but doesn't write the result into the google spreadsheet. It does though if I run the same code in Notebook. This is why I'm puzzled.

Comment: I solved the problem by putting everything in one function. I think this is something to do with how google authorizes access to spreadsheets and how Notebook processes results from different cells. It works now when I run the file from my shell.